# find, save and remove duplicate values from more then one array

Tags: php, arrays

first array

```
[0]=> Brian
[1]=> A
[2]=> Leo
[3]=> A
[4]=> Mike
```

second array

```
[0]=> 1
[1]=> 2
[2]=> 3
[3]=> 4
[4]=> 5
```

I want to check if in first array there are duplicates, if yes, save only the first occurrence of that value, the other removes, remember those keys, and delete them from the second array too. In the end i want to have

first array

```
[0]=> Brian
[1]=> A
[2]=> Leo
[3]=> Mike
```

second array

```
[0]=> 1
[1]=> 2
[2]=> 3
[3]=> 5
```

I tried with this but second array does not have duplicates so it won't work for both array:

```
array_values(array_unique($array));
```

Comment: Are you expected inputs/outputs correct? What happens to the 4 in your second array in the output?

Comment: in the first array, I removed the third key because values were duplicated, and then I saved 3 key and removed from the second array too

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in functions for you to use here.  Loop over the "first array".  Add items to a new array if they're not already in the new array.  If the _are_ already in the new array, use the current index to delete the same index from "second array", re-key "second array" with `array_values()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did

```
array_values(array_unique($array));
```

This will give unique values of `$array`, but you won't find which index of second array needs to be unset.

---

**Approach #1:**

Your best shot is a simple for loop with an `isset` check. If we find the value already present in our `$set`(a new temp array), we unset that index from both original arrays, else we preserve it.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    'Brian',
    'A',
    'Leo',
    'A',
    'Mike'
];

$arr2 = [
        1,2,3,4,5
];

$set = [];

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    if(!isset($set[$value])) $set[$value] = true;
    else{
        unset($arr1[$key]); // foreach creates a copy of $arr1, so safe to unset
        unset($arr2[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/BQ9mA

---

**Approach #2:**

If you don't like for loops, you can use array wrappers to do this. You can use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to make first array values as keys and second array values as arrays. Note that this would only preserve the latest key value pairs, so we do a [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to only maintain first occurrence pairs.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    'Brian',
    'A',
    'Leo',
    'A',
    'Mike'
];

$arr2 = [
        1,2,3,4,5
    ];

$filtered_data = array_combine(array_reverse($arr1),array_reverse($arr2));
print_r(array_keys($filtered_data));
print_r(array_values($filtered_data));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/mlstg

Comment: Approach #2 is not resolving the issues, please check how the output should look like. Approach #1 is good but you forgot to add the array_unique to arrays

Comment: @ririririri Approach #2 works fine. It may not be in the order, but the usual keys and their respective values in 2nd array are correct.

Comment: @ririririri array_unique is not at all needed for first approach. I hope you are following my code steps.

Comment: in you output keys are like this: 0,1,2,4 and it should be like this: 0,1,2,3

Comment: @ririririri For that, you can just do array_values($arr1); and array_values($arr2); in the first approach at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This simply builds a temp array using the values from your 2 arrays.

Because we use values of $a1 as the key, dups get overwritten and therefore lost. The `array_keys_exists()` check makes sure the first Dup is used and not subsequent dups. Then we just split the array into the two input arrays.

```
$a1 = ['Brian', 'A', 'Leo', 'A', 'Mike'];
$a2 = [1,2,3,4,5];

#temp array created using values of $a1 as key so dups get dropped because they are reused

foreach ($a1 as $i=>$a) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists($a, $new)){
        $new[$a] = $a2[$i];
    }
}
$a1 = array_keys($new);
$a2 = array_values($new);

print_r($a1);
print_r($a2);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Brian
    [1] => A
    [2] => Leo
    [3] => Mike
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
```

Comment: This is not good, please check again, how the output should look like.

Comment: Ok, made a small mod and now I think output matches your spec

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `array_unique` preserves keys so you can easily use it to filter the second array too:

```
$firstArray = array_unique($firstArray);
$secondArray = array_intersect_key($secondArray, $firstArray);

var_dump(array_values($firstArray), array_values($secondArray));
```

From the docs of [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> Note that keys are preserved. If multiple elements compare equal under the given sort_flags, then the key and value of the first equal element will be retained.